Measure to calculate value based on number of days selected in slicer
I have a measure attempting to calculate a value based on number of days selected on a date slicer.  Mathematically I want to take the Goal, which is monthly, divide it by days in the month, multiplied by number of days selected.  Independently the measures appear to calculate correctly.

Day_Selected Measure:
Day_Selected = 
VAR FirstDay = CALCULATE(
MIN('Calendar'[Date]),
ALLSELECTED('Calendar'[Date])
)
VAR LastDay = CALCULATE(
MAX('Calendar'[Date]),
ALLSELECTED('Calendar'[Date])
)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
COUNT('Calendar'[Date]),
DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],FirstDay,LastDay))

DaysinMonth Measure:
DaysInMonth = DAY(EOMONTH(Min('Calendar'[Date]),0))

However when I string them together into 1 measure I don't get the expected result:
   Day_Goal_Piece = RELATED('Goal - Piece'[Goal])/RELATED('Calendar'[DaysInMonths])*[Day_Selected]

I expect to calculate 2,142,067.2.  The current answer reflects 102,003.2, which is simply the Goal / DaysInMonths.  The Day_Selected measure referenced in the above measure doesn't seem to calculate.
I am using a traditional Star schema between MR Summary fact table with Calendar and Goal - Piece dimension tables,  MR Summary joins to Calendar on the Date field and Goal - Piece joins to MR Summary on the Line field.
I've tried a few DAX variations to calculate Day_Selected to see if that helps, but the result doesn't change.  I am not sure where to go next.


Looks like you are using Calculated Columns instead of Measures. Calculated Columns get calculated and set during dataset refresh time, and are not affected during report runtime interactions (ie slicers, filters have no affect). Ultimately Day_Goal_Piece needs to be a Measure.

How correct you are!  What a simple thing I overlooked.    Thank you!

Day_Goal_Piece needs to be a measure.  It was built as a calculated column.
I created the Day_Goal calculated column as this:
Day_Goal = RELATED('Goal - Piece'[Goal])/RELATED('Calendar'[DaysInMonths])

Then created revised Day_Goal_Piece to this:
Day_Goal_Piece = Min('MR Summary'[Day_Goal])*[Day_Selected]

